# TypeError: 'DeferredGeneratorList' object is not callable in Python Code

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying to download the whole Youtube playlist as MP3, this code below is giving me a `TypeError: 'DeferredGeneratorList' object is not callable`, I tried googling it, I found no similar errors at all, is there something I'm doing wrong? and / or, is there any other way I can use to achieve that?

Code:

```
import os
import subprocess

from pytube import Playlist, YouTube


def run(pl):
    # get parent directory; VERY IMPORTANT!!
    # INCLUDE LAST SLASH AFTER FOLDER NAME
    # e.g. /home/username/Folder/ or C:\Users\Username\Folder\
    filepath = input("Please enter the filepath of the directory where this script is located:\n")
    # get linked list of links in the playlist
    links = pl.video_urls()
    # download each item in the list
    for l in links:
        # converts the link to a YouTube object
        yt = YouTube(l)
        # takes first stream; since ffmpeg will convert to mp3 anyway
        music = yt.streams.first()
        # gets the filename of the first audio stream
        default_filename = music.default_filename
        print("Downloading " + default_filename + "...")
        # downloads first audio stream
        music.download()
        # creates mp3 filename for downloaded file
        new_filename = default_filename[0:-3] + "mp3"
        print("Converting to mp3....")
        # converts mp4 audio to mp3 audio
        subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i',
                        os.path.join(filepath, default_filename),
                        os.path.join(filepath, new_filename)
                        ])

    print("Download finished.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = input("Please enter the url of the playlist you wish to download: ")
    pl = Playlist(url)
    run(pl)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Totenkopf/Downloads/test/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    run(pl)
  File "C:/Users/Totenkopf/Downloads/test/main.py", line 13, in run
    links = pl.video_urls()
TypeError: 'DeferredGeneratorList' object is not callable
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the whole error traceback message.

Comment: What line of code gives the error? Can you use icecream or print statements to check where the code fails?

Comment: Sorry about that, I included the whole error message

Comment: It looks like `video_urls` is a plain attribute, not a callable function.  Why are you calling it?

Comment: That's right, my bad, thank you, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

video_urls is a list not a method. Call video_urls without ().

Comment: Nice! Found the solution on their playlist doc site: https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/playlist.html